# Use Flink in my IDEA, but run error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc，how to configure my scala version in the intelliJ?

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at akka.actor.setup.ActorSystemSetup$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ActorSystemSetup.scala:36)
    at akka.actor.setup.ActorSystemSetup$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ActorSystemSetup.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at akka.actor.setup.ActorSystemSetup$.apply(ActorSystemSetup.scala:36)
    at akka.actor.setup.ActorSystemSetup$.create(ActorSystemSetup.scala:42)
    at akka.actor.RobustActorSystem$.create(RobustActorSystem.scala:55)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:125)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:113)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.createRpcService(MiniCluster.java:758)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.start(MiniCluster.java:257)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:120)
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError is most likely caused by passing invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` usually occurs if you mix up Scala versions. For example, it could be caused by different dependencies which were built against Scala `2.11` and `2.12`. Please check that all dependencies and also the cluster use the same Scala version.